# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token ï»¿

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to upgrade my project to webpack version 2.

After I got all my typescript compiling and webpack building I tried to run my site.  I ended up getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

This is in my webpack `bundle.js` file.  I went to the file to see what it is and found these chars:

**ï»¿**

The cursor was in between the ï and the ».

Those chars are at the start of a few of the npm packages I downloaded.  (I downloaded them with `yarn`.)

Searching bundle.js I can see those chars are in my bundle a few times:

- At the start of jquery-color
- At the start of jquery-inputmask
- At the start of jquery-mask (yes I have both masks..)
- One more that I don't recognize (about getSignedRequest).

**How did these strange symbols get there, and how I can get rid of them?**

Comment: thats the UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Hmmm, must have been added in the newer version...  Well, at least I know what it is.  Off to google to find a fix.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I added the `webpack-utf8-bom` plugin and it took care of it for me.

This is the npm page for the plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-utf8-bom

This is the usage from that page:

```
// import plugin 
var BomPlugin = require('webpack-utf8-bom');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    // Add plugin in plugins list 
    // true for adding bom 
    // false for removing bom 
    new BomPlugin(true)
  ],

 ...
};
```

**The key part is that it worked backwards from what I would have expected.**  I would have thought that false would have gotten rid of the BOM chars, but actually using true got rid of the error.

```
new BomPlugin(true)
```

I when I looked the chars had been replaced by a red dot.  My guess is that the plugin formatted them correctly so that they did not confuse the browser.